# Excluding Matches With Regular Expressions

Tags: python, regex

Hi I have a pattern that I can identify with python regex but I want to return everything but the match

with this function I can extract the year of the string

```
def stripyear(string):
    p_year = re.compile('[2][0][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9]')
    ym = p_year.findall(string)
    return ''.join(ym)
```

so `stripyear('UTMSIRGAS200020150409')`will return `'20150409'` but i want it to return

```
'UTMSIRGAS2000'
```

i.e. the opposite

I tried this patter `'\b(?!([2][0][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9])\b)\w+'` and it works if there was a space before the patter in [here](http://regexr.com/50agd) but python does not like it.

thanks for any help.

Comment: I think you could use `re.sub` and replace the match with an empty string instead.

Comment: Thanks. now my code is a  one liner :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `re.sub` to replace with empty string:

```
re.sub("[2][0][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9]", "", input)
```

Comment: kudos now it is a one liner  `func = lambda x:  re.sub("[2][0][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9]", "", x)`

Comment: You can replace `[2][0]` with `20` and, if you wish, `[0-1]` with `[01]`, which saves a character, which could be important if you want to use this on [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).